# How to fit 30 images within a rectangle of maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, image

Hi i'm facing a problem where i need to fix 30 images within a rectangle of `752px`

**Question:** i need to fix `30 (160 X 120)` images within a `752px` of rectangle by maintaining aspect ratio

**Note:** my images are of `160 X 120` i want to maintain aspect ratio

**For better view here is codepen:** https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/abBVvQq

**Below is my problem:**

```js
$(function(){
    var imagesStr = '';
    for(var i = 1; i <= 30; i++){
          imagesStr += `<li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x120?text=${i}"/></li>`;
     }
   $('.image-wrapper').html(imagesStr);
})
```

```css
.image-container{
   width: 752px;
   height:122px;
   border:1px solid yellow;
   border-radius:3px;
  z-index:1;
}

.image-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="image-container">
     <ul class="image-wrapper">
       
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why set `height: 122px` if you want "a square of 752px"?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc, sorry i meant rectangle

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex:1 1` on child item to make them of same width, and then make image `width:100%`, it will maintain aspect ratio.

```js
$(function() {
  var imagesStr = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    imagesStr += `<li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x120?text=${i}"/></li>`;
  }
  $('.image-wrapper').html(imagesStr);
})
```

```css
.image-container {
  width: 752px;
  height: 122px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.image-wrapper li {
  flex: 1 1;
}

.image-wrapper li img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-container">
  <ul class="image-wrapper">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that's good but images are not visible can't we increase height maintaining **aspect ratio**?

Comment: According to the simple math, the answer is no, until whether you remove some items or increase the width of parent.